# How to have multiple placeholders with different colors in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the text from a form input from the placeholder to be grey and for another input, white. How could i resolve this problem?

`<input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="...">`

Comment: select the id of the input you want grey and give it grey styling, select the other and give it the other color

Comment: for example `#address::placeholder{color: grey;} #address2::placeholder{color: white;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use css:

In order to style a placeholder you need to write `::placeholder` in the css line.
Because you need 2 different colors, give the `input` tag an `id`.
Then make the css using the id like this: `#`, then the id, and then the `::placeholder`.

like this:

```
<input id="greyph" placeholder="...">
<input id="whiteph" placeholder="...">
<!-- ph = PlaceHolder -->
```

the css will be:

```
#greyph::placeholder {color: grey;}
#whiteph::placeholder {color: white;}
```

note that you don't have to color a placeholder to grey because this is the default